# How to get Password history?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I want to get last three passwords used (set) by user and don't want to set them again when they are going to set again same password. Which API should use to get password history. I often visit this link

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no "previous password" in any of the APIs.

I would use a one-way hash function to save the last passwords inside a datastore table, and then compare with these.

I know of no Google product that will offer something like that.

Comment: This is correct. You cannot pull previous passwords via any Apps API.